# failed to create menuitem click method in resource directory

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, contextmenu, menuitem, resourcedictionary

I'm struggling with this below problem. my style file in resource directory. but it can't apply click method to context menu item. it's showing below this error. please help me how can i achieve this.

**Error : "'Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'OnMenuItemClick'.' Line number '10' and line position '35'."**

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="date" ObjectType="{x:Type src:DateTime}"/>
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
<ContextMenu x:Key="ListViewContext" Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle1}">
    <MenuItem Header="Create" Click="OnMenuItemClick" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="GridItemContext" Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle1}">
    <MenuItem Header="Modify" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
</ContextMenu>
<Style x:Key="ListViewGrid" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFDFDFE2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#faf2f2"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListViewContext}"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource GridItemContext}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border CornerRadius="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  >
                    <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFDFDFE2">
                        <Grid Background="#FFEFEFEF" Name="Trg" Height="20">
                            <GridViewRowPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Trg" Property="Background" Value="#FFDFDFE2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Trg" Property="Background" Value="#FFDFDFE2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the above code, the error I got was:

> Error 1   'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute
>   to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event
>   handler for the Click event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root
>   element. Line 10 Position 35

This is how I fixed it:

1) Added x:Class attribute to the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
x:Class="WpfApplication4.Dictionary1"
```

2) Added a C# class file to the project, Code below:

```
public partial class Dictionary1 : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Dictionary1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And then, the project built fine.